# Selecting direct children with Postgres ltree using Elixir

Tags: database, postgresql, tree, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to select any children that are a single level below with ltree.

For example, if I had Car.Ford, the query would grab any child with a path such as Car.Ford.Fiesta, Car.Ford.Fusion, Car.Ford.Mustang.

How can I build this query using ltree, if possible, specifically using Elixir?

Right now I'm using

```
from c in query, where: fragment("path <@ ?", c.path)
```

But it returns all entries with the path in it.

Comment: Well, you are obviously gonna end up using `fragment` but aside from that, I think you need to dive into the `ltree` docs and find out how to do what you want -> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out.

The documentation on Postgres states that the {} in an lquery limits the number of labels it will match, the documentation from the developers clarifies that this is actually to limit the number of levels to search.

```
'My.Example.*{1}'
```

That will match anything one level below a path starting with My.Example